# How to port forward to rds instance from python script

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssh, ssh-tunnel

How do I port forward to an rds instance from a bastion host to a `rds sql server` instance?

Typically, I port forward from a bastion host like so: `ssh -L 20004:targeted-mssql-rds.aws.com:1433 knn0926@my_bastion_host.com` and that will allow me to call `localhost:20004` for my db connection. However, that doesn't seem to work or to be the correct process for connecting to a db through port forwarding out of a python script. Every time I try to connect I get the following error: `pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00, [HYT00] [Mircosoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired(0) (SqlDriverConnect))`. I'm also on a mac so I'm not sure if that makes a difference compared to windows.

I think my code is pretty straightforward for connecting:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import io
import os

#listing drivers
for driver in pyodbc.drivers():
  print(driver)

#Make db connection
sql_connect = pyodbc.connect("Driver = {ODBC Driver for SQL Server}; SERVER=localhost,20004; database=simpsons;uid=my_user;PWD=my_pwd, autocommit=True")

cursor.execute('''select * from spp.transactions where acx_num > 1000''')
```

Am I supposed to be connecting to my bastion and mssql instance in the python code itself? I'm confused as to why its failing and how to properly connect it to my code.

Comment: Do you have the ssh session up and running in the background before you run your python script? You would need that tunnel up and running prior to running the python script.

Comment: Is the Python code running directly on the macOS host, or is it running inside a Docker container? If the latter then instead of `localhost` (which is the Docker container itself) try `host.docker.internal` (which is the macOS host) and you may need to specify a bind address with `-L 0.0.0.0:20004:targeted-mssql-rds.aws.com:1433` as well.